# VBA does not arrange my workbooks if one or more is minimized

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writing a piece of code to arrange workbooks in tiles. But I want to do this for a select few opened workbooks.
The way I go about it is I loop through all opened workbooks and those that don't meet a condition are minimized.
Excel doesn't have trouble with this when I do it manually by going to **View -> Arrange -> Tiled**.
It arranges only unminimized workbooks.

However, when I want VBA to do the same thing, it only arranges them when there are no minimized workbooks. Here is what I tried.

```
Dim wb As Workbook

For Each wb in Workbooks
   If (condition) Then
      wb.Windows(1).WindowState = xlMinimized
   End If
Next wb

Windows.Arrange xlArrangeStyleTiled
```

Again, the Arrange works if the number of minimized workbooks is zero.
Further, the issue seems to be only with the tiled Style of Arrangement. For Vertical, Horizontal or Cascade, the program doesn't mind if there are minimized workbooks and works as expected.
However, I want the workbooks to be arranged in Tiles.

Edit:
Here's an example to illustrate the purpose of this program.
Let's say I have 5 open workbooks. I am currently working with workbooks 1, 2, and 3 and I want to see them simultaneously on the screen. Workbooks 4 and 5 are irrelevant to me at the moment so I don't want them taking up screen space when I tile my workbooks. Therefore workbooks 4 and 5 will be minimized so that my screen will be shared among workbooks 1, 2, and 3 when I tile them.

Comment: Then you just set the `WindowState` to `xlNormal` before tiling them... right? What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe I didn't make it clear enough why I go through the trouble of minimizing some of them.
Let's say I have 5 workbooks opened, I want workbooks 1 to 3 to be tiled but not 4 and 5 as they are not part of the task I'm working on currently.
Therefore workbooks 4 and 5 will be minimized leaving all the screen space to the 3 workbooks I care about when I tile them.

Does that make more sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the Windows.Arrange method, there is a second optional parameter to determine whether all windows are included in the "arrangement", or only the visible windows of the active workbook. While I know that FALSE is meant to the default value, I've seen that explicitely using FALSE can force the tiling of all windows. So maybe try:

```
ThisWorkbook.Windows.Arrange xlArrangeStyleTiled, False
```

Comment: Definitely tested it. And retested it just now. Three workbooks ... Book1 visible (and contains the VBA), Book2 minimized, and Book3 also visible. Run the code (alt-F8) ... not via the IDE. Definitely tiles Book1 and Book3.

Comment: Wow, I didn't expect this to work. It actually does work for me from a module. I run all my code from a module in the PERSONAL macro workbook.  
If there's at least 1 minimized workbook, then specifying `False` for ActiveWorkbook parameter works, but not specifying it doesn't work.

But since the default is False, theoretically this shouldn't change anything. Is this a bug or something?